# NoRouteToHostException while hadoop fs -copyFromLocal

Tags: java, apache, hadoop

I installed hadoop 2.5.1 on CentOS7.0

and I'm using 3 computers with below hosts file, the same as all 3 computers

I'm not using DNS.

> XXX.XXX.XXX.65 mccb-com65  #server
>
> XXX.XXX.XXX.66 mccb-com66  #client01
>
> XXX.XXX.XXX.67 mccb-com67  #client02
>
> 127.0.0.1      localhost
>
> 127.0.1.1      mccb-com65

I execute the command

**$hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /home/hadoop/hdfs/hdfs/s_corpus.txt hdfs://XXX.XXX.XXX.65:9000/tmp/**

I met below error message

> INFO hdfs.DFSClient: Exception in createBlockOutputStream
>   java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host     at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)  at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:529)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.createSocketForPipeline(DFSOutputStream.java:1526)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.createBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1328)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1281)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:526)
>   15/02/27 16:57:40 INFO hdfs.DFSClient: Abandoning
>   BP-1257634566-XXX.XXX.XXX.65-1425014347197:blk_1073741837_1013
>   15/02/27 16:57:40 INFO hdfs.DFSClient: Excluding datanode
>   XXX.XXX.XXX.67:50010    **<-- the same as another salve node XXX.XXX.XXX.66**

I turn off all firewall of both computers mccb-com66 and mccb-com67 as below state shows.

**$systemctl status iptables**

> iptables.service - IPv4 firewall with iptables    Loaded: loaded
>   (/usr/lib/systemd/system/iptables.service; disabled)
>    Active:
>   inactive (dead)

and Additionally I also turn off selinux.

datanode and nodemanager are alive in both machines
I can check the state 
jps and 
http://mccb-com65:50070 and 
http://mccb-com65:8088

What I'm missing?

Could you anybody help me???

Comment: the ipv6 is disabled or not?

Comment: I disabled, I can validate with the command **$cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6**    the result - $
**1**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though I turn off the iptables, it's not valid solution.

After I open port one by one with firewall-cmd, it works..

for all slaves (66 and 67)

```
$firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8042/tcp
$firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=50010/tcp
$firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=50020/tcp
$firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=50075/tcp
$firewall-cmd --reload
```

and then it works.

However, since I cannot open all ports which need to run Hadoop App,

turn off firewalld is reasonable such as

```
$systemctl stop firewalld
$systemctl disable firewalld
```

and check the status

```
$Systemctl status firewalld
```

Answer (score 0):

your /etc/hosts should contain:

```
XXX.XXX.XXX.65 mccb-com65 #server

XXX.XXX.XXX.66 mccb-com66 #client01

XXX.XXX.XXX.67 mccb-com67 #client02
```

Remove

```
127.0.0.1 localhost

127.0.1.1 mccb-com65
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest, I've changed the hosts file you suggest, however it is not the solution.